# Integral Algebraic Scheme has Cartier Divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I have a question about a step in a proof in Badescu's "Algebraic Surfaces" (p. 2):

[image]

Why the conditions that the $k$-scheme $X$ is ***integral*** 
and ***algebraic*** ensure that for an invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}_1$ there exist a Cartier-Divisor $D$ with $\mathcal{L}_1 = \mathcal{O}_X(D)$?

What could failure if the given scheme $X$ wouldn't have this properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some results in both directions that I became aware of from reading [[Lazarsfeld](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-18808-4), §1.1]. We denote by
$$l\colon \operatorname{Div}(X) \longrightarrow \operatorname{Pic}(X)$$
the canonical homomorphism sending a Cartier divisor to its associated line bundle. The kernel of $l$ is the subgroup $\operatorname{Div.princ}(X) \subseteq \operatorname{Div}(X)$ of principal Cartier divisors [[EGAIV$_4$](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1967__32__5_0), Prop. 21.3.3(*i*)].

### When $l$ is surjective

The first result directly answers your question about why integrality is sufficient for $l$ to be surjective.

**Proposition** [[EGAIV$_4$](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1967__32__5_0), Prop. 21.3.4]**.** *Let $X$ be a scheme such that one of the following properties holds:*

1. *$X$ is locally noetherian and $\operatorname{Ass}(\mathcal{O}_X)$ is contained in an affine open subset of $X$.*
2. *$X$ is reduced and the set of the irreducible components of $X$ is locally finite.*

*Then, the canonical homomorphism $l$ is surjective.*

On the other hand, even without integral hypotheses, one has the following:

**Theorem** [[Nakai](https://doi.org/10.2307/1993908), Thm. 4]**.** *Let $X$ be a projective scheme over an infinite field $k$. Then, the canonical homomorphism $l$ is surjective.*

Note that in any of these cases, the homomorphism
$$\frac{\operatorname{Div}(X)}{\operatorname{Div.princ}(X)} \longrightarrow \operatorname{Pic}(X)$$
induced by $l$ is an isomorphism.

### When $l$ is *not* surjective

We have the following:

**Theorem** [[Kleiman](https://doi.org/10.1080/00927870008827181), §2; [Schröer](https://doi.org/10.1007/s000130050470), §2]**.** *There exist non-reduced thickenings of*

1. *a complete, non-projective, connected, non-singular threefold; and*
2. *a non-separated, connected, non-singular curve;*

*such that the canonical homomorphism $l$ is not surjective.*

The original version of example 1 is due to Kleiman (see [[Kleiman](https://doi.org/10.1080/00927870008827181), §2]), and a similar example appears in [[Schröer](https://doi.org/10.1007/s000130050470), §2.1]. An erroneous version of Kleiman's example first appeared in [[Hartshorne](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0067839), Ex. 1.3]. The threefold one starts with is Nagata's [[Nagata](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255454111), Ex. 2] and Hironaka's (see [[Hartshorne](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-3849-0), App. B, Ex. 3.4.1] or [[Shafarevich](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-38010-5), §6.2.3]) for Kleiman's and Schröer's examples, respectively.

Example 2 is due to Schröer [[Schröer](https://doi.org/10.1007/s000130050470), §2.2].

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. One remark about an idea meanwhile occured to me to settle the problem in a more elementary way:Generally, an effective Cartier divisor is characterized by the data ${\displaystyle \{(U_{i},f_{i})\}}$ where the $U_i$ cover $X$ and the $f_i$ are ***non zero divisor*** sections from $\Gamma(U_i, \mathcal{O}_X)$ which are compatible on the intersections $U_i \cap U_j$. Wlog we can assume (after refining) that $U_i= Spec(R_i)$ are affine and - I think that this is here the main point - by integrability of the ring every $0 \neq f_i \in R_i$ is a non zero divisor.

Comment: @KarlPeter I am a bit confused by your sketch: you want to start with a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$, and produce a suitable Cartier divisor, right? For the integral case, you just take a section of $\mathcal{L}$ on an affine open subset of $X$, which gives a rational section $s$ on all of $X$. As you point out, the key here is that locally all you need to do is find a nonzerodivisor on this (dense) affine open subset, which gives a rational section of $\mathcal{L}$. The principal divisor $D = \operatorname{div}(s)$ then satisfies $\mathcal{L} \simeq \mathcal{O}_X(D)$.

Comment: This is the proof in EGA, and this proof (and the one for Nakai's result) is sketched in \[[Lazarsfeld](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-18808-4), Ex. 1.1.5\].

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mixed itup. So here I just have choose for $U_i$ as above a compatible family of local sections $f_i \neq 0$ then - by integrability -I'm done. Or do I oversee some substantial point?

Comment: @KarlPeter What you said would work, but I wouldn't know how to construct such $f_i$ without going through a construction like the one I described: You choose one open subset $U$ where $\mathcal{L}$ is trivial, and a non-zero section $f \in \Gamma(U,\mathcal{L})$. By integrality, you can extend $f$ to a rational section $s \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{L} \otimes \mathcal{K}_X)$. One then checks that this $s$ gives a section of $\mathcal{K}_X^*$ under the identification $\mathcal{L}\rvert_U \simeq \mathcal{O}_U$; this is the content of the first paragraph of the proof in EGA.

Comment: Do you have a reference/argument for the step that if the scheme $X$ is
integral then a local section $f \in \Gamma(U,\mathcal{L})$ can be
"twisted" to a global section 
$s \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{L} \otimes \mathcal{K}_X)$?

Comment: I encountered just a theorem of similar shape that provides that for a coherent sheaf
$\mathcal{F}$ a section $s \in \Gamma(D(f),\mathcal{F})$ 
can be twisted to $\bar{s} \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{L}^n)$ 
for $n$ big enough. Can your statement be reduced to this one?

Comment: @KarlPeter One way to see this is that $f \in \Gamma(U,\mathcal{L})$ gives rise to $s_U \in \Gamma(U,\mathcal{L} \otimes \mathcal{K}_X)$ (since $\mathcal{L} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{L} \otimes \mathcal{K}_X$), and $s_U$ lifts to a global section $s$ of $\mathcal{L} \otimes \mathcal{K}_X$ since this sheaf is flasque (it is isomorphic to $\mathcal{K}_X$ by \[Stacks, [Tag 01XS](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01X5)\]). This last reference in fact gives an easier way to see that the rational section $s$ exists; see \[Stacks, [Tag 02OZ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02OZ)\].